# Office 365 Shared Calendar without invitations or reminders?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, calendar, outlook-2016

I'd like to create a calendar in Office 365 Outlook which can be added to by several users, but produces no invitations or reminders. Is this possible to achieve? The users check this particular calendar regularly and the invitations/reminder popups become very distracting in addition to their regular personal calendars.

Comment: What did O365 support say about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of days more research plus 3 calls to O365 support...

1. In Outlook, click on 'Folders', highlight the group which contains the shared calendar.
2. In the Ribbon click 'Home > Membership > Unsubscribe'. User will no longer receive invitations, or reminders for that calendar but will still be able to view/add/edit as permissions allow.

NB. The Organizer of an appointment will always be automatically attending the appointment and therefore it appears in their personal calender, meaning that they still get reminders. Currently it's not possible to prevent this behaviour and the organizer must delete then appointment in their personal calendar in order to prevent reminders popping up.

Comment: I don't see "Membership" in calendar home\ within O365?

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the other answer to work, but it might be about how the calendar admin can disable emails. Individual members can disable emails like this:

1. Open the calendar in Outlook
2. In the ribbon, Group > Group settings > No emails or events